# PHP How to distinguish 0 from 0.0

Tags: php, operators

I have to distinguishing (0 and 0.0 ). How I can do that??

```
<?php 
$val1 = '0';
$val2 = '0.0';
if ($val1 == $val2) echo "OK" ; 
?>
```

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: or u can go stcmp($val1, $val2) === 0 ? "match" : "no match";

Comment: @Bert canyou post an aswer, to have things  in order, you will get some points too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As comment by Bert use `===`

```
<?php 
$val1 = '0';
$val2 = '0.0';
if ($val1 === $val2) echo "OK" ; 
?>
```

`===` Returns true if first `variable` is equal to second `variable` , and they are of the same `type`

for more info please read http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

Answer (score 0):

`if ($val1 == $val2) echo "OK" ;` should be `if ($val1 === $val2) echo "OK" ;`. In PHP, `===` returns `TRUE`, when the variables being compared are equal and are of the same type. See [**operator comparison**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the differences between == and === operators, and when they should be applied.

> $val1  ==  $val2   Checks if they are **equal**      TRUE if $a is equal
>   to $b after type juggling.
>        $val1 ===  $val2   Checks if they are **identical**  TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.

try this:

```
if ($val1 === $val2) {
   echo "These two are identical";   // This gets executed
} else if ($val1 == $val2) {
   echo "These two are equal but not identical";
}
```